# bootstrap modal dialog from another modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using the twitter bootstrap modal plugin and I have a modal dialog from which, on the click of a button, I want to show a smaller modal dialog.

What is happening is that my second smaller modal dialog is not really modal, because I can still access the first dialog underneath it ( click buttons select text etc..)

I do have the data-backdrop="static" attribute setup for the second modal dialog but it does not seem to work properly.

Is this normal behavior ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the normal behavior. The `z-index` given to the backdrop and the modal are fixed, meaning that the 2nd backdrop will still have a lesser value than the first modal.

It might work if you increase the `z-index`s of the 2nd elements on showing.

IMHO you may find easier to hide the 1st modal while displaying the 2nd - since the modal was not meant to be used in multiple instances at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Sherbrow is right.. and the way to get around it is to target the ID of the first modal, and change it's z-index to something BETWEEN the 1050 that the new modal is set to, and the 1040 that the backdrops are set to..

in my case, I used:

```
#modal1 {z-index: 1048;}
```

Now, when I have #modal1 open and I click a link to another modal, the second modal covers #modal1, but the backdrop does not!

Comment: My second modal comes in front of the first modal, but I can still access the first modal. I am able to perform operations on the first modal when the second one is open.